# Google reCAPTCHA, ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key

Tags: recaptcha

I am using Google recaptcha V2 API. I register the domain divostar.com, 127.0.0.1 and everything was working fine. Now, I have added a new domain 10.25.0.1, and it doesn't seem to work for this. I get the error `ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key`. Each of the domains are written one per line. What really can be the problem?

Comment: you should add the domain name test.com not the ip

Comment: Thanks for your input @CMS. The app does not have a domain name yet. On localhost (127.0.0.1), I don't get the message. It is on a test server so I just put the IP of the test server.

Comment: I know that google supports localhost for testing and it will even show that its on localhost, the question is if they support plain ip addresses

Comment: Thanks again for your input. Would have to check that out.